# Elasticsearch data does not match mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-5

I am migrating elasticsearch prod data from 1.4.3v to 5.5v, for which I am using [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade.html). When I try to reindex old ES index to new ES index the reindexing fails with an exception `Failed Reason: mapper [THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC] cannot be changed from type [long] to [float]. Failed Type: illegal_argument_exception`

ES mapping for task_history index in ES 1.4.3v

```
{
   "task_history": {
      "mappings": {
         "task_run_hist": {
            "_all": {
               "enabled": false
            },
            "_routing": {
               "required": true,
               "path": "org_id"
            },
            "properties": {
               "RUN_TIME_IN_MINS": {
                  "type": "double"
               },
               "THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "account_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "store": true
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

ES mapping for task_history index in ES 5.5v (this mapping gets created as part reindexing)

```
{
  "task_history": {
    "mappings": {
      "task_run_hist": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_routing": {
          "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "RUN_TIME_IN_MINS": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "account_name": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "store": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample data

```
{
  "_index": "task_history",
  "_type": "task_run_hist",
  "_id": "1421955143",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "RUN_TIME_IN_MINS": 0.47,
    "THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC": 46,
    "org_id": "xxxxxx",
    "account_name": "Soma Acc1"
  }
},
{
  "_index": "task_history",
  "_type": "task_run_hist",
  "_id": "1421943738",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "RUN_TIME_IN_MINS": 1.02,
    "THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC": 65.28,
    "org_id": "yyyyyy",
    "account_name": "Choma Acc1"
  }
}
```

2 Questions

1. How elasticsearch 1.4.3 is saving float numbers when mapping for `THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC` type is `long`?
2. If it's a data issue in old ES how can I remove all float numbers before starting the reindexing process?

For 2nd option I am trying to list all documents having float numbers using below query, so that I can verify once and delete it, but below query still lists documents having `THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC` as non floating numbers.

Note: Groovy scripting is enabled

```
GET task_history/task_run_hist/_search?size=100
{
   "filter": {
      "script": {
         "script": "doc['THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC'].value % 1 == 0"
      }
   }
}
```

**Updated with solution provided by Val**

When I try below script in reindexing, I get a runtime error. Listed below. Any clue on what is getting wrond here? I added additional condition to convert `RUN_TIME_IN_MINS` to float as your original script pointed out an error in `RUN_TIME_IN_MINS` field.  `mapper [RUN_TIME_IN_MINS] cannot be changed from type [long] to [float]"`

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://esip:15000"
    },
    "index": "task_history"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "task_history"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "if (ctx._source.THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC % 1 != 0) { ctx.op = 'noop' } ctx._source.RUN_TIME_IN_MINS = (float) ctx._source.RUN_TIME_IN_MINS;",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Runtime error

```
{
  "completed": true,
  "task": {
    "node": "wZOzypYlSayIRlhp9y3lVA",
    "id": 645528,
    "type": "transport",
    "action": "indices:data/write/reindex",
    "status": {
      "total": 18249521,
      "updated": 4691,
      "created": 181721,
      "deleted": 0,
      "batches": 37,
      "version_conflicts": 0,
      "noops": 67076,
      "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
      },
      "throttled_millis": 0,
      "requests_per_second": -1,
      "throttled_until_millis": 0
    },
    "description": """
reindex from [host=esip port=15000 query={
  "match_all" : {
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}][task_history] updated with Script{type=inline, lang='painless', idOrCode='if (ctx._source.THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC % 1 != 0) { ctx.op = 'noop' } ctx._source.RUN_TIME_IN_MINS = (float) ctx._source.RUN_TIME_IN_MINS;', options={}, params={}} to [task_history]
""",
    "start_time_in_millis": 1502336063507,
    "running_time_in_nanos": 93094657751,
    "cancellable": true
  },
  "error": {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [],
    "script": "if (ctx._source.THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC % 1 != 0) { ctx.op = 'noop' } ctx._source.RUN_TIME_IN_MINS = (float) ctx._source.RUN_TIME_IN_MINS;",
    "lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "null_pointer_exception",
      "reason": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's very much possible that the very first document you created in ES 1.x had a long value (see `"THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC": 46,`) and the mapping was created on that basis. Then all subsequent values (whether float or not) would be coerced to long. You need to create your mapping in ES 5 **before** starting your reindex process.

Comment: @Val: In that case documents having float numbers will throw exception and stop reindexing process and mapping is correct. It has to be of type `long`.

Comment: You obviously need to set `double`in your ES 5.x mapping in order to accommodate your different values

Comment: @Val: Mapping has to be `long` type, is there a way to delete all float/double value documents from ES 1.4.3v?

Comment: I would use a script while reindexing to modify your document. See the reindex documentation for an example. No need to delete the data in the source index

Comment: @Val: What are you suggesting to modify?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously want to keep your existing ES 5.x mapping with a `long`so all you need to do is to add a script to your reindex call that modifies the `THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC` field to a `long`. Something like this should do:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://es1host:9200",
    },
    "index": "task_history"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "task_history"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "if (ctx._source.THROUGHPUT_ROWS_PER_SEC % 1 != 0) { ctx.op = 'noop' }" },
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: but then the data will be wrong. Instead if I can delete all float numbers and reindex only long numbers, this way few data will be missing and it will not be misleading.

Comment: In that case, you can ignore the document if your modulo condition holds true. See my updated answer

Comment: I am getting a runtime exception after a bit of modification, updated my question for more information.